# multiple assigning array in foreach?

Tags: php, arrays

I am a newbie in PHP... there are 4 arrays which I want to display, but It does not display anything...

**Please refer with the code**

```
$new_strip_from_name[] = $strip_from_name;
$new_from_name[] = $from_name;
$new_to_name[] = $to_name;  
$new_lastdata[] = $lastdata;

echo "<table style='border: 2px solid black; text-align:left'>";    
    foreach($new_from_name as $from_name2){
        foreach($new_lastdata as $lastdata2){
            foreach($new_to_name as $to_name2){
                foreach($new_strip_from_name as $key => $value){                
                    if((strpos($lastdata2, $value) !==FALSE)){                  
                     echo "<tr>";
                     echo "<td>$from_name2</td>";
                     echo "<td>$to_name2</td>";
                     echo "<td>$lastdata2</td>";
                     echo "</tr>";  
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
echo "</table>";
```

sample array

```
$new_strip_from_name = array("okay");
$from_name; = array("john", "mar", "jeff");
$to_name; = array("phil", "india", "japan");
$lastdata; = array("john@okay", "mar@okay", "jeff@not");
```

desired output

```
john    phil    john@okay
mar     india   mar@okay
```

Comment: What is your desired output, example please. Also example of the input arrays. As I dont think nesting foreach loops like that will generate what you want anyway.

Comment: Show your HTML text input code.

Comment: do foreach{} foreach instead of foreach{foreach{}}. That makes no sense here !

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo - can you please show a bit of example...

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I just want to display all in an arrays with the following condition is met

Comment: @RiggsFolly - is that possible sir??

Comment: It's horrible to see what your desire is here, but what you do know is echoing a row for every item in new_from_name * every item in new_last_data * .... So you will probably get hundreds of outputs !

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo - thats ryt sir

Comment: I think you should really consider a different structur, a class with the attribute from_name, to_name, _last_data, $strip_from_name, and then have a array with class objects. and do one foreach over them. However this is a guess, because i can't see what you want to do for sure

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo - sir.. could you please do some example... coz i dont know..

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo - its typo error sir... thanks... I edit my question.

Comment: I will make an example once I understand what you want ! What is in the arrays at the top ? Is it correct that you want size_of($new_from_name ) * size_of($new_lastdata) * size_of($new_to_name ) * size_of($new_strip_from_name) rows ?

Comment: Bee, if you wont help us by providing the information requested in my first comment I for one am off to other things and will vote to close this question as off topic for this reason [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo - yes sir...

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo - the question is edited with the desire display...

Comment: @RiggsFolly - the question is edited with the desire display...

Answer (score 0):

Okay now we see what you want!! but it wont work like this. The best way would be to create a class for that ->  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php. But here a basic solution which can work:

```
$messages = array();
$message = array();
$message['from'] = "john";
$message['to'] = "phil";
$message['lastdata'] = "john@okay";

array_push($messages, $message);
```

Do this for every message or whatever it is and then this:

```
foreach ($messages as $message){
  if (strpos($message,"okay") !== false){
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$message['from']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$message['to']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$message['lastdata']."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";  
   }
}
```

Comment: so its something like this ?? $messages = $from_name . $to_name . $last_data; Can you please refer from the code

Answer (score 0):

This anwser should work with your current data structure, but this is NOT clean. It is not the way it should be, you should have 1 element for each message, not 4 arrays with the 4 parts of the message, this could really lead to some serious mixup problems. You should change the collection or creation of the data if possible. But anyhow try this:

```
$new_strip_from_name[] = $strip_from_name;
$new_from_name[] = $from_name;
$new_to_name[] = $to_name;  
$new_lastdata[] = $lastdata;

echo "<table style='border: 2px solid black; text-align:left'>"; 
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($new_from_name); $i++){
  if (strpos($new_lastdata[$i],"okay") !== false){
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".$new_from_name[$i]."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$new_to_name[$i]."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$new_lastdata[$i]."</td>";
   echo "</tr>"; 
  }
} 
echo "</table>";
```